# Mapping custom collection's property to column in EF

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'd like this class:

```
public class InvertedList<T> : List<T>{
    public bool IsInverted { get; set; }
}
```

when used in the entity like this:

```
public class Parent {
    public InvertedList<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

to map into database tables like

```
CREATE TABLE Parent (
    Child_IsInverted bit
);

CREATE TABLE Child (
    ParentId int
)
```

I've tried putting [Column] on the IsInverted property, [ComplexType] on InvertedList class, but the property is always ignored.

Is there any way to do something like this or anything similar? 
Of course I can do it manually like

```
public class Parent {
    public bool Child_IsInverted { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

But I really don't like to put all those Child_IsInverted properties (I'll have quite a lot of such invertable lists) on Parent entity. The only way I can think of to at least partially implement this would be to have separate domain and db models, and transform it using the repository - this way I could work using desirable model, but it looks like a little bit too much effort for such a task. Can you offer any other options?

Comment: Just think of how you would store this in a relational database. Since that's not possible there's no way to do this with EF.

Answer (score 0):

When EF deserialize a List<> (everything implementing ICollection<>) it does not serialize other properties than the content.

Just a suggestion, Compex types that could be an option does not support generics and does not support navigation properties and you here have both.

Comment: That's right, and what about any other options? Maybe some conventions, advanced mappings or anything like that could help to achieve this? The only way I can think of to at least partially implement this would be to have separate domain and db models, and transform it using the repository - this way I could work using desirable model, but it looks like a little bit too much effort for such a task. Can you brainstorm anything else?